# How to set value when using an existing component with vuejs/storybook

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, storybook, quasar-framework

I would like to map stories in Storybook using Quasar components. I would like to pass on their properties 1:1 so that they can be changed in Storybook. Unfortunately, I have not been able to set a value. In concrete terms, the code looks like this:

// preview.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Quasar from 'quasar';
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";
import messages from "../src/i18n";
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

// Import quasar extras, required for fonts/icons
import 'quasar-extras/fontawesome'
import 'quasar-extras/material-icons'
import 'quasar-extras/roboto-font'
import 'quasar/dist/quasar.css'
import '../src/css/app.scss'
import storyRouterDecorator from "./storyRouterDecorator";

Vue.use(Quasar, { config: {}, directives: {} });
Vue.use(VueI18n);
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: "de-de",
  fallbackLocale: "en-us",
  messages
});

Vue.prototype.$t = function(...args){
  return i18n.t(...args);
}

Vue.prototype.$storybook = true;

const preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: {argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*"},
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/
      }
    }
  },
  decorators: [
    // This global decorator allows for the use of vue router components in stories.
    // It might be able to facilitate some routing as well, but that has not been tested yet
    storyRouterDecorator({},
      {
        routes: []
      })
  ],
};

export default preview;
```

// VTabs.vue

```js
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { QTab } from "quasar";
import { QRouteTab } from "quasar";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "VTabs",
  components: {
    QTab
  },
  props: QRouteTab.options.props
})
</script>

<template>
  <q-tabs
    no-caps
    class="col-auto text-subtitle2 text-left"
    :exact="false"
    active-class="text-primary"
  >
    <slot />
  </q-tabs>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

// VTabs.stories.vue

```js
import VTabs from './VTabs.vue';
import { transformVueComponentPropListToArgTypes } from "../../../../.storybook/storybookHelpers.js"
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  component: VTabs,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  argTypes: transformVueComponentPropListToArgTypes(VTabs.props),
  args: {
  }
};

const Template = (args, {argTypes}) => {
  return {
    props: Object.keys(argTypes),
    components: {
      VTab
    },
    directives: {},
    setup() {
      let model = ref('tab1')
      const updateModel = (event) => model.value = event
      return { args, model, updateModel }
    },
    template:
      `
        <q-tabs v-bind="$props" v-on="$listeners" @update:modelValue="updateModel" :modelValue="model">
          <template v-slot:default>
            <v-tab name="tab1" label="Tab 1" />
            <v-tab name="tab2" label="Tab 2" />
          </template>
        </q-tabs>
      `,
  }
}

export const standard = Template.bind({})
```

Now, I can change

```
        <q-tabs v-bind="$props" v-on="$listeners" @update:modelValue="updateModel" :modelValue="model">
```

to

```
        <q-tabs v-bind="args" v-on="$listeners" @update:modelValue="updateModel" :modelValue="model">
```

and here the property for the selected tab is applied, but nothing else. If i change back, I can apply everything except the property for the active tab.
I thing, i have to combine somehow both, but how?